# apk shows file list instead of installing

Tags: android, apk

Some users are reporting that when downloading my apk and clicking it opens up a file list of the contents of the apk. Nothing has changed with the apk and it was working fine a couple months ago but now doesn't work. I have multiple versions and they have tried to install all of them with the same problem. My Android 6.0 is working fine and i can't replicate it but another user running 6.0 on T Mobile tablet is experiencing it. It is hosted on the web for users to download and This is what happens when they click the downloaded APK once it is downloaded, any thoughts?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/myjg8sqw8njsqpv/Screenshot_2017-04-17-10-09-24.png?dl=0

Comment: Where do they click? In which app?

Comment: Once it's downloaded from where I have it hosted on the web, chrome asks to open file. When the user is brought to the downloads folder it opens like the screen shot instead of showing the install dialog

Comment: I've also tried using the regular I internet browser and Firefox and still doesn't show install dialog

Comment: Use a file explorer app to go to the download directory. Inspect the file name. Install using file explorer.

Comment: Tried that instead of using the browser open file method however it still does not show install dialog but rather shows the above picture